# EKEventEditViewController Add and Cancel buttons not responding

Tags: objective-c, calendar, eventkit, ekevent, ekeventkit

I am trying to add a calendar event using `EKEventEditViewController`. I have setup a `EKEventEditViewController` properly with an `EKEventStore`, `EKEvent`, and its `editViewDelegate` as the presenting view controller. The `EKEventEditViewController` presents itself correctly, but when I press either 'add' or 'cancel', `didCompleteWithAction` does not called in `EKEventEditViewDelegate`. But, I do get this error (no crash though):

```
[EKCalendarItemLocationInlineEditItem isSubitemAtIndexSaveable:] - Location Inline Edit Item didn't have a text label on its non conference location cell; will return NO
```

You can see [here](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/EventKitUI.framework/EKCalendarItemLocationInlineEditItem.h) that `EKCalendarItemLocationInlineEditItem` is in the `EventKitUI` framework.

It seems like this has something to do with location but I can't seem to figure it out. Has anyone ever encountered this error, or have any tips on how to further debug? Thanks! I am running iOS 11 and Xcode 9.0.1.

Comment: Could you show some of your code creating the event.

Comment: I have this same problem and I am setting the delegate

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did not set the `editViewDelegate` before presenting the `EKEventEditViewController`. Without the delegate, the Buttons 'add' and 'cancel' do not respond.

Creating the EventView and presenting (Swift)

```
let eventView: EKEventEditViewController = EKEventEditViewController()
eventView.event = event
eventView.editViewDelegate = self
eventView.eventStore = eventStore

present(eventView, animated: true) { }
```

ObjC

```
EKEventEditViewController *eventView = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
eventView.event = event;
eventView.editViewDelegate = self;
eventView.eventStore = eventStore;

[self presentViewController:eventView animated:true completion: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have set your delegate and are still hitting the dreaded `[EventEditor] -[EKCalendarItemLocationInlineEditItem isSubitemAtIndexSaveable:] - Location Inline Edit Item didn't have a text label on its non conference location cell; will return NO`, you probably haven't set `EKEventEditViewController.eventStore`.

Here is a working sample code showing how to configure properly `EKEventEditViewController` :

```swift
func showNewEvent(askPermission: Bool) {
    let store = EKEventStore()
    if askPermission {
        store.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.showNewEvent(askPermission: false)
                }
            }
        }
        return
    }

    let event = EKEvent(eventStore: store)
    event.title = "New event name"
    event.notes = "Some notes"
    event.availability = .busy
    event.isAllDay = ...
    event.startDate = ...
    event.endDate = ...
    event.structuredLocation = ...

    let vc = EKEventEditViewController()
    vc.event = event
    vc.eventStore = store // <-- this needs to be the same event store you used for EKEvent
    vc.editViewDelegate = self
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This code is inspired by this amazing post https://dev.to/nemecek_f/how-to-use-ekeventeditviewcontroller-in-swift-to-let-user-save-event-to-ios-calendar-d8

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the issue is that you don't dismiss their view controller when the delegate gets called:

```swift
func eventEditViewController(_ controller: EKEventEditViewController, didCompleteWith action: EKEventEditViewAction) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

---

> Implement this method to dismiss the modal event edit view controller.

*(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkitui/ekeventeditviewdelegate/1613928-eventeditviewcontroller)*